# jmeter performance analysis

Tags: performance, server, jmeter, performance-testing

I am running performance test for perf environment.

Below is the results:

```
CPU Utilization

Server  Apdex   Resp. time  Throughput  Error Rate  CPU usage   Memory
per001205       0.970.5     220 ms      2,670 rpm   0.0009 %    493.00% 2.2 GB
per001206       0.950.5     280 ms      2,670 rpm   0.0043 %    516.00% 2.4 GB
per011079       0.830.5     526 ms      2,670 rpm   0.0034 %    598.00% 2.5 GB
per011080       0.670.5     1,110 ms    2,670 rpm   0.0026 %    639.00% 2.6 GB
```

Can you comment on how the avergage response time? is it accepted?
I can see CPU usage is more than 100% , is it dangerous ?

How should i improve this? i am running it for 250 users.

Comment: How are you getting this output? Can you give more information on the underlying system and the tool used to capture this information?

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all check out [CPU usage mismatch or usage over 100%](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/apm/new-relic-apm/troubleshooting/cpu-usage-mismatch-or-usage-over-100) article.
2. Consider other monitoring method, i.e. go to hosts directly and check CPU usage via your operating system built-in commands or use [JMeter PerfMon plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test) to either confirm the picture or get an alternative view of CPU load. Depending on the result you have 2 options:

   - Either individual servers CPU usage is acceptable and you can decide whether throughput good or not
   - Or you need to fix the issue in your application code: using [profiling tools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_(computer_programming)) for the programming language, your application is written in detect the most CPU intensive functions and refactor them to be less processor-time-hungry